# JTable : Complex Cell Renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

There are a lot of time, that I'm trying to make the Cell Renderer in the JavaOne 2007's talk maked by Shanon Hickey, Romain Guy and Chris Campbell, in the pages 38 and 39 (that you can find here : http://docs.huihoo.com/javaone/2007/desktop/TS-3548.pdf).

I asked Romain Guy, and Chris campbell, but without success, they say that they cannot pulish the source code.

So, any one can, give an idea, or even a source code on how to make this complex cell renderer ?
 I learned this slides of many times, they say :

1)Cell Renderer: Column Spanning
Viewport clips column contents
and
2) Viewport moves to 
expose the right text 
for each column

I don't understand that, please can you give more in depth explanations ?

Cheers

Comment: I think a lot of the UI elements in the slides can be found in the book Filthy Rich Clients. They also reference it at the end. Definitely give it a look.

Comment: I bought the book in 2007, I read it, and I can say that I have it on my mind, this book just explains how to beautify the GUI by adding some static/dynamic effects, animations and so on, it didn't talk about the JTable or the CellRenderer !!!

Answer (score 2):

- Windows 7
- JDK 1.7.0_21

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class ComplexCellRendererTest {
  private static boolean DEBUG = true;
  private JRadioButton r1 = new JRadioButton("scrollRectToVisible");
  private JRadioButton r2 = new JRadioButton("setViewPosition");

  public JComponent makeUI() {
    String[] columnNames = {"AAA", "BBB"};
    Object[][] data = {
      {new Test("1", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"), "4"},
      {new Test("2", "1234567890\nabcdefghijklmdopqrstuvwxyz"), "5"},
      {new Test("3", "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc\ndddddddddddd"), "6"},
    };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
      @Override public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
      }
    };
    final JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
    table.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,1));
    table.setRowHeight(56);
    for(int i=0; i<table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
      TableColumn c = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
      c.setCellRenderer(new ComplexCellRenderer());
      c.setMinWidth(50);
    }

    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DEBUG = (e.getSource()==r1);
        table.repaint();
      }
    };
    Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    box.add(r1); bg.add(r1); r1.addActionListener(al);
    box.add(r2); bg.add(r2); r2.addActionListener(al);
    r1.setSelected(true);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new ComplexCellRendererTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  static class ComplexCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {
    private final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(2, 999999);
    private final JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    public ComplexCellRenderer() {
      super(new BorderLayout(0,0));

      scroll.setViewportView(textArea);
      scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
      scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
      scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
      scroll.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
      scroll.setOpaque(false);
      scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
      textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
      //textArea.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
      textArea.setForeground(Color.RED);
      textArea.setOpaque(false);
      label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,0,1,1,Color.GRAY));
      setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      setOpaque(true);
      add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(scroll);
    }
    @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
      JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
      boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
      Test test;
      if(value instanceof Test) {
        test = (Test)value;
      } else {
        String title = value.toString();
        Test t = (Test)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
        test = new Test(title, t.text);
      }
      label.setText(test.title);
      textArea.setText(test.text);
      Rectangle cr = table.getCellRect(row, column, false);
      if(DEBUG) {
        //Unexplained flickering on first row?
        textArea.scrollRectToVisible(cr);
      } else {
        //Work fine for me (JDK 1.7.0_21, Windows 7 64bit):
        scroll.getViewport().setViewPosition(cr.getLocation());
      }
      if(isSelected) {
        setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
      } else {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      }
      return this;
    }
  }


}
class Test {
  public final String title;
  public final String text;
  //public final Icon icon;
  public Test(String title, String text) {
    this.title = title;
    this.text  = text;
  }
}
```

Comment: `//textArea.scrollRectToVisible(cr); //Unexplained flickering on first row`, din't understand, nothing flickering, test with `JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);`, or there are two another modes

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for reporting (Sorry for not explaining enough). Using `textArea.scrollRectToVisible(cr);`: When I change the width of the header's column, text in the table cell of first row moves over a little. `JViewport.setScrollMode(JViewport.SIMPLE_SCROLL_MODE);` remain about the same in my environment.

Comment: nice CellRenderer and... no flickering here: _MacOS 10.7.5 with Java 1.7.0_21-b12 and Windows 7 with Java 1.7.0_21-b11_

Comment: @bobndrew Thanks for reporting. I will edit this code to be able test the column resizing.